# Short story: push a button to kill a stranger

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story in 80s (I have in mind it was in a kids compendium of (sci-fi?) short stories).

A person takes part in a gameshow, and if he presses a button a stranger wearing a jumpsuit on a screen in a departure lounge will drop dead and the contestant wins a huge prize. At the end of the story the winner (who pressed the button), realises they are in a jumpsuit, in a departure lounge...

Someone else raised this question a few years back (unanswered), and they also remembered:

*the contestant lives in slums, gets selected for participation in game show, has no choice but to go on. (I think) they terrorize him with nasty spiders (he has a phobia) and to make them stop (and win a fantastic holiday(?)), he just has to press a button, but doing so will kill a stranger he can see on a screen. The stranger appears to be in some form of departure lounge.*

Does anyone recognise this plot? It's definitely not Button, Button by Richard Matheson.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall any other stories in the collection, or what the collection itself looked like?  Was it in English?

Comment: It sounds like Button, Button by Richard Matheson.

Comment: I looked at button button, but doesn't seem to involve an airport departure lounge/TV screen.

Comment: I had multiple compendiums when I was younger, all in English. I have tracked down a few on ebay, but this story doesn't appear in there.

Comment: This looks like the other referenced question:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129470/help-identifying-sci-fi-short-about-game-show-with-button-to-kill-stranger

Comment: Sounds like something Robert Sheckley would write.

Comment: Might help in some general way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_paradox

Comment: Yes that referenced question is asking about the same short story.